# Custom metadata loader Mapping

Tags: data-loader, custom-metadata

I am using custom metadata loader to perform the insertion of custom metadata with 200 records. Although I have mapped the values correctly I am hitting the below mapping error.

[image]

Note: There is no such field called description. Don't know why it is showing that field.

I am using CSV UTF - 8 since it accepting only this type. Not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the file as standard '.csv' not '.csv UTF-8'
2. Make Sure the file has DeveloperName, Label. Description is not required here.

[image]

Comment: @H R Thank you. Yes we need to upload it as CSV. The problem was there was a trailing space included in one of the cell that was causing this error. The error message was misleading however.